# Handling multiple textfield with single onChange react hooks

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

I have some issues with managing controls over some textfields.
I have an object

```
let obj = {
  [
   {
    name:"a",
    adress:[{"foo":a1,"bar":a1}],
    comment:"aaaaa"
   },
   {
    name:"b",
    adress:[{"foo":b1,"bar":b1}],
    comment:"bbbbb"
   }
  ]
}
```

And I generate dynamic textfields

```
{obj.map((item, i) => {
 return <TextField name = {item.name} value={item.comment} onChange={(e)=>{handleComment(e,item.name)}}/>
})}
```

I want to modify **comment** for every specific textfield based by its name

```
const handleComment = (e,name) =>{
  e.preventDefault();
  setObject({...obj,comment:e.target.value})
}
```

I can't managed the right way to do it. I can't figure it out how to do it. If you guys can help me, it would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, so what's the question? All I'm seeing is a bunch of code.

Comment: I can't managed the right way to do it. I can't figure it out how to do it. Thanks

Comment: You need to manage obj in state using useState().Then update the state based on the inputs

Comment: If you could create small sandbox demo may be I can help you with the same..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ciao, you could use an array in `handleComment` function in which you can copy current state. Then update that array and set the state.
Lets say you have:

```
const obj = [
    {
      name: "a",
      adress: [{ foo: "a1", bar: "a1" }],
      comment: ""
    },
    {
      name: "b",
      adress: [{ foo: "b1", bar: "b1" }],
      comment: ""
    }
  ];
  const [object, setObject] = useState(obj);
```

and `return` like:

```
return object.map((item, i) => {
    return (
      <TextField
        name={item.name}
        value={item.comment}
        onChange={(e) => {
          handleComment(e, item); 
        }}
      />
    );
  });
```

Then your `handleComment` becomes:

```
const handleComment = (e, item) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let result = object;   // copy state
    result = result.map((el) => {  // map array to replace the old comment with the new one
      if (el.name === item.name) el.comment = e.target.value;
      return el;
    });
    setObject(result); // set state with new comment
  };
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-textfield-forked-8xssw?file=/src/index.js) a codesandbox example.